# tool to record web traffic and create scriptable "objects"?

Tags: web-traffic

Anyone have experience with tools that can capture web traffic and create scriptable "objects" to recreate this traffic? The objects could then be used to create scripts to drive functional or load tests. For the capture itself, a lot of tools take the proxy approach (soapUI, grinder etc.), but what we need is a transparent proxy, because some components are not able to use a proxy. Seems like soapUI has the TCP tunnel option, which is transparent, but they don't create independent, scriptable objects for traffic regeneration.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Microsoft web proxy that allows you to record and playback web traffic, called [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler). See [here](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) for some of the advanced features.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/fiddler/) is the fiddler blog, and some [more info](https://mvark.blogspot.com/2010/07/http-traffic-export-options-in-fiddler.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20WebDevelopmentTipsTricksTrivia%20%28Tech%20Tips,%20Tricks%20&%20Trivia%29) on the export capabilities.